# Java regular expressions, dot match

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a string in the form of:

```
{something here}{something here}{something here}
```

etc
In summary there are brackets with text or anything inside (any character).
I want to split it into an array (using Java's `String.split(regex)` function). The regex I used is `\\{.*\\}` but it's not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `Pattern` and `Matcher` and extract the parts.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis how can I use them?

Comment: i believe you're regex is correct, but it's greedy, meaning that the first bracket and the last bracket will match, i.e. "something here}{something here}{something here" will be consumed by the .*     . try \{.*?\} instead

Comment: @AndyThomas there isn't any code for that. Just 
'String[] objs = s.split("\\{.*\\}");'

Comment: @ApollonDigital - Ah. You're providing a regular expression for what you want as parts, but split() takes a regular expression for the *separator* between the parts. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument in the split() method specifies the ***separator*** between the parts, not the parts themselves.

As suggested by Sotirios Delimanolis, you can achieve your goal by repeatedly matching a pattern. The example code below gets the the text inside the braces.

```
    String val = "{alpha}{beta}{delta\nepsilon}";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "\\{(.*?)\\}", Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( val );
    while ( matcher.find() ) {
        String part = matcher.group(1);
        System.out.print( String.format("%s,", part));
    }
```

The `.*?` expression provides a reluctant match, which prefers to match as few characters from the string as possible. If you just use `.*`, that's a greedy match - the first match will be the entire string.

You mentioned in a comment on a deleted answer that your "something here" strings can contain new lines. For the '.' to match newlines, you need to use the `Pattern.DOTALL` flag, as shown above.

The call to `matcher.group(1)` gives you the text matching the [capturing group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg) `(.*?)`. If you wanted the braces included, you could omit the parantheses and simply call `matcher.group(0)` to get the entire match.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input="{something here}{something here}{something here}";
    String[] parts=input.substring(1,input.length()-1).split("\\}\\{");
    for(String s:parts)
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

output:

```
something here
something here
something here
```

Comment: Using the .substring(), .replace(), .split() with single chars as params is my standar 'hack' for these things. Since I usually need to do things like that I think it's time to learn a more proper way to implement them.

Comment: +1 for an answer that actually works. Note that it fails if there are extra characters at the head, tail, or between the `}{` pairs. See also the Pattern/Matcher solution suggested by @SotiriosDelimanolis and illustrated in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I agree it is not the most beautiful solution. But it works. Power to simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

In regex, the * is greedy, meaning that it will consume as many characters as possible. This means that the regex:`\{.*\}` will match the entire string, as the .* will match "something here}{something here}{something here". 
putting a ? after a * will make it behave in an un-greedy fashion, meaning that it will only consume characters up until the next expression can match.
therefore, try `\{.*?\}` as your regex instead

Comment: A reluctant match is necessary, but it won't be sufficient in the OP's call to `String.split()`.

Answer (score -1):

You know the quote about regexps ...
Well, it doesn't help.

What does help, however, are (like usual) tests. And regular expressions can be tested online using websites such as [RegExp Planet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)

So, when using as test string `{a}{long}{text with spaces}` I can find as a "good" regexp the following `\{([^\}]*)\}`. And, to quote the source site

> Regular Expression    {([^}]*)}
>
>   as a Java string  "\{([^\}]*)\}"

Cause one shouldn't forget to add the double backslashes

Comment: While this is a regular expression, it will 1) be greedy, and 2) won't be helpful in the OP's call to `String.split()`.

Comment: Finding the **exact** regular expression is left as an exercise to the OP (after all, a testing tool is provided). What I wanted to describe here was more the process than the result.

Comment: The link and the suggestion to test could be a good comment, but they don't answer this OP's specific question.